# Clear text when losing focus with google maps API autocomplete and force selection

Tags: javascript

I'm using workscout theme on wordpress and I'm trying to figure this out.  I have it setup with google maps API to find a location when someone inputs it, however I want it to force to use one of google's suggestions.  If they type in anything anything or don't select from one of google's autocomplete then I want it to clear the textbox.  I'm sort of new so if you can answer in a descriptive way of doing this I'd appreciate it.

Thank you.

Not many things, I'm sort of a newb.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.